# Button Breaks React Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, electron, jsx

I want to add button to my form to dynamically add inputs. Yet I found that, if i added a button to my form that simply logs to the console, (and when I try to add inputs) it logs and then the form breaks. The front end window of my Electron app crashes (doesn't exit but turns grey) and automatically restarts on the same page without the dialog open that contains the form.

Here is a snippet of my form code:

TaskCreation.js

```
return (
        <div className="modal-body">
            {values.products.map((product, i) => {
                return(
                    <div key={i}>
                <Form.Row>
                    <Form.Group as={Col} controlId={"keywords-" + i}>
                        <Form.Label>Keywords (e.g. '+box +logo +tee')</Form.Label>

                        <Form.Control
                            value={product.keywords.join(' ')}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                        >
                        </Form.Control>
                    </Form.Group>
                </Form.Row>
...

            <div style={{ marginTop:'10px' }}>
                <button onClick={() => console.log(123)}>Add Product</button> // this breaks when clicked
            </div>
...
);
```

Any help is welcome, let me know what other information I should provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the button activates the 'submit' from form. So, you can try somethings. Add the atribute type="button" to your button, and/or use ".preventDefault()".

```js
const handleButton = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  console.log(123)
}
```

```js
<div style={{ marginTop:'10px' }}>
  <button type="button" onClick={handleButton}>Add Product</button> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel! Can you explain why it didn't work when I didn't set the type of the button? Did it default to submit?

Comment: Exactly! When is a form button, for default his type is submit